# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' getting issue in RTL

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, testcase

While writing test case in jest, I get the error `Property 'value' does not exist on type HTMLElement`. When I click the `savebtn` in the text field of `firstName`, it should contain `ana`. However, I am not able to access `firstName.value`

```js
const firstName = screen.getByText("First name");
fireEvent.change(firstName, {target: {value: 'ana'}});
const savebtn = screen.getByTestId("savebtn");
fireEvent.click(savebtn);
expect(firstName.value).toBe('ana');
```